# Using sed regex for string replacement

Tags: regex, linux, string, sed

I am trying to replace a string in the config file.
I would like to run something like this:

OS

> (docker image php:8.1-apache-buster)
>
> > Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
> >
> > > sed (GNU sed) 4.7 Packaged by Debian

Possible inputs:

```
post_max_size = 4M
post_max_size = 24M
post_max_size = 248M
...
```

Example output (any user given value):

```
post_max_size = 128M
```

Example cmd:

```
sed -i 's/(post_max_size = ([0-9]{1,})M/post_max_size = 128M/g' /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
```

[image]

Joining regex with strings does not work here.

It works when I run string replace without any regex

```
sed -i 's/post_max_size = 8M/post_max_size = 128M/g' /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
```

This works only if the value of the post_max_size is set exactly to 2M. I would like to be able to make a change with regex regardless of the value set.

I searched the Internet and `sed` cmd docs but did not find anything which fits my use case.

Comment: Please replace image with its text.

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Try `sed -i -E '/post_max_size = /s/([0-9]{1,})M/128M/' /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match optional spaces with `[[:space:]]*`, the  `-E` for extended-regexp and use group 1 noted as `\1` followed by your replacement like `\1128M`

```
sed -E -i 's/(post_max_size[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*)[0-9]+M/\1128M/g' /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
```

Comment: There is something missing here. I have tried this and similar commands, but it does not trigger string replacement. @C-nan cmd worked.

Comment: @DevWL What is your os?

Comment: its a dockeriesd container of php & Apache image "Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"

Comment: @fpmmurphy command also worked:
sed -i -E '/post_max_size = /s/([0-9]{1,})M/128M/' /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini

Comment: @DevWL Maybe there is a different amount of spaces `sed -E -i 's/(post_max_size[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*)[0-9]+M/\1128M/g' /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini`

Comment: @DevWL See it [working here](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vzg1RUHXVUG9WF@jIL@4JD43sSK@OLMqNTraqrggMTnVKjZWyxaZoxltoGsZq@2rH2NoaGThq5@urmBjY6OghKJbwVbBxJcLXcgIq5iFr9L//wA)

Comment: Yes this works also in my use case, Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The following should work:

```
sed -i 's/^post_max_size = .*/post_max_size = 128M/g' /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
```